# Animating Pointcloud Color

Tags: python

I am trying to animate changing colors in a pointcloud in python but I'm not able to get the keyframing right.

I'm not sure my setup is super ideal but I am using https://github.com/TombstoneTumbleweedArt/import-ply-as-verts to import my pointcloud with colors.

The color attributes are stored in `(point_cloud.data.color_attributes[0])` and `to_anim` is a np array with time dimension 0 that contains the color of each vertex at each time.

Here's an attempt:

```
point_cloud = bpy.data.objects[-2]
obj = (point_cloud.data.color_attributes[0])

for i_frame in range(1, to_anim.shape[0]):
    for idx, v in enumerate(obj.data):
        v.color = to_anim[i_frame][idx][3:]
        v.keyframe_insert('color', index=-1, frame=i_frame)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() could not make path to "color"
```

I'm pretty new to blender this might not even be the right way to approach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance